# Any AFSK libraries for Android? (for data input via Android headphone jack)

Tags: android, audio, signal-processing, frequency

I'm trying to implement a audio jack data interface using AFSK and a micro-controller.

Through searches I've seen a couple implementations that use iPhones, such as this:
http://www.creativedistraction.com/demos/sensor-data-to-iphone-through-the-headphone-jack-using-arduino/comment-page-1/#comment-243826

There they used "Perceptive Development’s SerialModem for iPhone", although that seems to contain a hex file and a circuit schematic?

I haven't been able to find anything by searching for "AFSK Android library", "FSK android library" or various other combinations of that. Does anyone know of a good source for these kinds of tools for Android?

Alternatively, is there a library that implements the simplified FFT that you could use to demodulate the data? Naturally you don't want to do a full FFT because you're just trying to distinguish between
(Ideas drawn from here: http://labs.perceptdev.com/how-to-talk-to-tin-can/) but I'm sure there's something like

I looked into spandsp, http://www.soft-switch.org/ , looking for more general DSP libraries. Not sure if these can be used on Android though.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You wouldn't normally use an FFT for FSK encoding/decoding.

Comment: And what would you use?

Comment: It depends on the exact modulation scheme. but typically you would use use a pair of filters plus threshold detectors and decision logic.

Comment: Know of any implementations I could look at? Or any other resources?

Comment: If you Google for "V.21 modem" then this is a simple 300 bps AFSK full duplex modem standard that is very simple to implement and for which there is a lot of documentation and probably even source code too.